# Parse json values into a single row

Tags: json, powershell

```
{
"value": [{
    "ExternalKey": "12345",
    "PortfolioId": "ABC",
    "InceptionDate": null,
    "TerminationDate": null,
    "Version": 2,
    "SourceRef": "ABC",
    "MasterSeries": [{
      "Points": [{
        "Date": "1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "Name": "XYZ Name",
        "Type": "IP",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Version": 1
      }],
      "ExternalKey": "12345",
      "Version": 1,
      "IsDeleted": false,
      "SourceRef": "ABC"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I tried to loop through each level and manually selecting the keys

```
ForEach($d in $json.value) { $row=$d.column1+","+ $d.column2 ..          
$rootProps = $d| Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -match "Property"} 
$rootProps | ForEach-Object { 
    if($_.Name -eq "MasterSeries") { 
        $d | select -Expand MasterSeries | select-object * -ExcludeProperty Points | ForEach { $row = $_.column1 + "," $_.column2 ..
    }
}
```

and so on..... but when I export it to Out-File "Export.csv" and try importing it gives me a UTF error. Is there a better way to achieve?

Comment: To make it pretty:  `get-content file.json | convertfrom-json | convertto-json`  There's only one value at the root with a group of properties underneath in a one element array.

Comment: thanks but there is a list within a list. MasterSeries is a list and Points is a list within Master series I need to get the values for those too. when I do get-content file.json | convertfrom-json | convertto-json   basically only the root level is displayed  "MasterSeries":  ""

Comment: Can you add what your expected output is for your example data?

Comment: You will need a little recursive function

Comment: So I need something like this: 
v=at the root level key/value
m=MasterSeries level key/value
p=lowest leaf within Master series key/value

v_ExternalKey,v_PortfolioId,....,m_ExternalKey,m_Version,.....p_ValueDate,p_Name,....

I achieved using the below but its hard coded and not efficient.

Comment: I achieved using the below but its hard coded and not efficient. 
        $output = @()   ForEach ($d in $json.value)   {
        $CSVLine=[pscustomobject]@{
        v_ExternalKey=$d.ExternalKey 
        v_PortfolioId=$d.PortfolioId
  
  .
        m_ExternalKey=$d.MasterSeries.ExternalKey
        m_Version=$d.MasterSeries.Version
  .
  
        p_ValueDate=$d.MasterPortfolioTimeSeries.Points.ValueDate
        p_Name=$d.MasterPortfolioTimeSeries.Points.Name
  .
  .
        }
        $output=$output + $CSVLine
    } 
    $output | Export-Csv -Path $FilePath -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps any, here's the typical way to loop through json properties in powershell 5 using the hidden psobject.properties.  You might search for "flatten json".

```
$a = get-content file.json | convertfrom-json
$a.value[0].psobject.properties | select name,value

Name            Value
----            -----
ExternalKey     12345
PortfolioId     ABC
InceptionDate
TerminationDate
Version         2
SourceRef       ABC
MasterSeries
```

Comment: thanks this is helpful, will search further for a more dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to create a [*recursive function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).
To make things easier, I recommend you to use the `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable` parameter which will return `[HashTable]` objects rather than `[PSCustomObject]` Objects

```
Function Get-Values($Object) {
    if ($Object -is [String]) { $Object } # A string is also Enumerable
    elseif ($Object -is [Collections.IDictionary]) { $Object.get_Values() | ForEach-Object { Get-Values $_ } }
    elseif ($Object -is [Collections.IEnumerable]) { $Object.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { Get-Values $_ } }
    else { $Object }
}
```

```
$Object = ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable '{
  "value": [
    {
      "ExternalKey": "12345",
      "PortfolioId": "ABC",
      "InceptionDate": null,
      "TerminationDate": null,
      "Version": 2,
      "SourceRef": "ABC",
      "MasterSeries": [
        {
          "Points": [
            {
              "Date": "1900-01-01T01:00:00+01:00",
              "Name": "XYZ Name",
              "Type": "IP",
              "Status": "Active",
              "Version": 1
            }
          ],
          "ExternalKey": "12345",
          "Version": 1,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "SourceRef": "ABC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

```
Get-Values $Object

12345
False
1
IP

Monday, January 1, 1900 1:00:00 AM
XYZ Name
Active
ABC
1
12345
2
ABC
ABC
```

Comment: thanks this is helpful, let me try to get the key as well along with the values as I need to export the output as csv

Comment: Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and create a new one if you need more help on retrieving the keys as well